# push docker container to a private repository from GITLAB CI

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

we are able to build and push the docker container to the private registry within GITLAB CE. However due to our deployment process we would like to push the same build also to another repository . But tagging it with the new repo name and pushing it leads to an authorization problem . Any suggestions how to make that happen ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to login to the registry you're about to push to before trying the actual push

```
docker login -p password -u username my.private.registry.com
docker build ...
docker push my:tag my.private.registry/my:tag
```

You could also read the documentation for running a local registry for hints on the syntax for building new tags:
https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-a-local-registry

Comment: yes - as said all of that works. I just want to push the same build to another repo . we do a docker tag original_name new_repo:tag. and then push in the same CI pipeline . for the second push I am getting an not authorized

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is replicate the steps you are doing for the first repo.

So if you are running these steps for the first one:

```
docker login -p password -u user registry.1.com
docker build
docker push
```

You will then need to do a new login to the next repository. If all you do for the next repo is to change the adress then you are not authenticated to that repository.

```
docker login -p password -u user registry.2.com
docker build
docker push
```

Make sure to have your credentials as variables. If you are using AWS ECR you can have a step where you run the `aws ecr get-login` command and output it into a file that you `eval` to pass it in.